# How to activate/run another processing script using controlp5 button

Tags: processing, control-p5

My current folder structure is like

```
- Parent
   - Child1
      - Child1.pde 
   - controlp5_GUI
      - controlp5_GUI.pde
```

I plan to use controlp5 inside controlp5_GUI.pde. My final objective is to run child1.pde when the user clicks "Activate Script" button. Is this doable in controlp5? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`exec()`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#exec-java.lang.String...-) to call the [`processing-java`](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Command-Line) command line utility to launch Child1.pde.
e.g.

```
Process sketch = exec("processing-java","--sketch=/absolute/path/to/yourSketch.pde","--run");
```

In your case controlp5_GUI.pde would call something like:

```
Process sketch = exec("processing-java","--sketch=/Users/mac/Desktop/xxx/Child1","--run");
```

There are a couple of caveats to take into account:

1. You need `processing-java` to be included into the `PATH` environment variable (otherwise you will need provide the absolute path to `processing-java` which lives in the same folder as the processing executable (in the folder where you've installed Processing).
2. The `--sketch` path needs to be absolute.

This [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680407/playing-pde-files-in-a-loop/42683106#42683106) might be helpful too.

If you need to control a sketch from another sketch using P5 you might find [ControlP5's frame example](https://github.com/sojamo/controlp5/blob/master/examples/extra/ControlP5frames/ControlP5frames.pde) useful.

Comment: Thanks George! I actually did what you propose. For testing purpose, I include ```exec("processing-java","--sketch=../Child1/Child1.pde","--run");``` at the end of my setup(). The script just did not work and it shows ```RuntimeException: Exception while attempting processing-java --sketch=/Users/mac/Desktop/xxx/ --run
Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize).```

Comment: The path to the sketch is incorrect then. You can try `exec("processing-java","--sketch="+sketchPath("../Child1/Child1.pde"),"--run");` which *should* be a relative path to Child1 if indeed Child1 is a sibling folder of controlp5_GUI as your questions states. Additionally you can use an absolute path. If the Child1 folder is inside `/Users/mac/Desktop/xxx/` you should be able to run `exec("processing-java","--sketch=/Users/mac/Desktop/xxx/Child1/Child1.pde","--run");`. Hopefully this makese sense. If you want to be 100% sure user Terminal to `cd` into the `controlp5_GUI` folder and...

Comment: ...try running the `processing-java` command with the `--sketch` and `--run` arguments from there. Once you've got the hang of paths and the Terminal commands runs just fine, you'd mirror the behaviour in Processing using `exec()` (just paying attention to double quotes, etc.). Does this make sense ? (If you're unfamiliar with Terminal there are plenty of tutorials out there (like [this one](https://tutorials.codebar.io/command-line/introduction/tutorial.html)) that cover basic file system navigation and running a command (such as `processing-java --sketch=/path/to/YourSketch.pde --run))

Comment: Thanks George, for all the explanation. I just tried the absolute path, and the error stays the same. Pretty sure I did not make any typing mistakes.

Comment: However, once I copied the command to the terminal, it opens the target file. So the error came from ```exec()``` function instead of the path

Comment: Good point regarding the paths. Re-reading your message I realise I've missed this part: "Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize)". This tells me the sketch was indeed launched, but crashed immediately. Does it make a difference if you use `launch()` instead of `exec()` ? It will be hard for me to debug why the crash happens. I've experienced VM crashes in processing due to hardware errors (OpenGL/GPU, USB, etc.) and c++ memory access errors (when java libs talk to native C++ libs via JNA/JNI/etc.): usually when this happens a log is saved (e.g. ~/hs_err_pid13421.log)

Comment: No worry! Interestingly, ```launch()``` did not cause any errors. Basically, nothing happens after I start my script lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245463/discussion-between-george-profenza-and-rieder).